# Hide Checkboxes when checked

Tags: jquery, laravel

I'm having some trouble looping a function through a list of checkboxes (created by a foreach function). 
When I try the code for a certain input id, it works, but when I try it for multiple it doesn't, and I'm quite sure that I'm doing something wrong with the for loop in the javascript part.
I'm trying to achieve, that when I check a checkbox, it disappears (the input text can stay).
This is my current approach:

```
<div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-8 col-md-7 col-lg-6">
  <div class="card-box">
    <h4 class="text-dark  header-title m-t-0 m-b-30">Redo Samples</h4>
    <div id='redo_div' class="text-center">
      <ul class="list-inline m-t-15">
        @php
        $i = 0;
        @endphp
        @foreach ($Redos as $Tubes)
        <li><input id="Redo_<?php echo $i; ?>" type="checkbox">{{$Tubes['TubeBarcodeID']}}</input></li>
        @php
        $i++;
        @endphp
        @endforeach
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  for (var i = 0; i > 0; i++) {
    $('#Redo_'.i).change(function() {
      if (this.checked)
        $('#Redo_'.i).fadeOut();
      else
        $('#Redo_'.i).fadeIn();
    });
  };
</script>
```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some class to your checkboxes, e.g. `fadeable`.

And then bind `change` to class:

```js
$('.fadeable').on('change', function () {
  if ( $(this).prop('checked') ) {
    $(this).fadeOut();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a `for` loop in your jquery, you can do it like this:

```
$('input[id^=Redo]').change(function() {
  if (this.checked)
    $(this).fadeOut();
  else
    $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

`$('input[id^=Redo]')` selects all input's that has an `id` starting with `Redo`, this way we don't have to change any of your HTML.

**Demo**

```js
$('input[id^=Redo]').change(function() {
  if (this.checked)
    $(this).fadeOut();
  else
    $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-8 col-md-7 col-lg-6">
  <div class="card-box">
    <h4 class="text-dark  header-title m-t-0 m-b-30">Redo Samples</h4>
    <div id='redo_div' class="text-center">
      <ul class="list-inline m-t-15">

        <li><input id="Redo_0" type="checkbox">code</input>
        </li>
        <li><input id="Redo_1" type="checkbox">code</input>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```